# How can I change the parent div on chekbox :checked?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a custom UI for checkbox by using the following code:

```
<div class="checkboxWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="receipt" name="receipt" id="receipt" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.checkboxWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* This is the invisible checkbox */
.checkboxWrapper input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 16px;
    z-index: 120;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* This is a div simulating a checkbox */
.checkboxWrapper:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 100;
    //margin: 16px 0 0 16px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(../images/checked.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Then I try to change the background image position when checkbox is checked:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked .checkboxWrapper:after {
    background-position: 16px 0;
    background-color: indianred;
}
```

Is it possible? Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LbSpX/

Comment: There's no way to traverse upwards through the DOM in CSS. If you wanted to get this to work, I'd recommend changing the background in Javscript (jQuery).

Comment: if you use label + input , you can have some options in CSS. If label and input are linked together you can use the label to draw a custom checkbox. iput should be ahead label in order to be able to select label from input state example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vhgqj/

Comment: @GCyrillus What I'm using now is this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GC2da/1/. I think it's my best option without using jQuery.

Comment: label brings accessibility abd checbox can be hidden. make sure it works with older browsers  too :), at least that you do not loose your checkbox .:)

Comment: Ah, so that's why they use label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css you could draw your custom checkbox from a label if structure is this :

`<input type="checbox" id="ckb" /> <label for="ckb">label</label>`
Css can be

```
input + label { /* style */}
input:checked + label {/* other style }
/* or and with before/after */
input + label:before { /* style */}
input:checked + label:before {/* other style }
```

example with the use of radio and drawn checbox : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vhgqj/

*example filters older using avanced selecteur to hide and draw input*

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above, here's the jQuery code that could accomplish this for you:

**CSS**

```
.checkboxWrapper.checked:after {
    background-position: 16px 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('input#receipt').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
    }
})
```

See it live on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LbSpX/2/